# Analyzing tones for a website

Tags: html, audio, web, analyzer

First of all, hello! I am new to... everything basically.

Is there a way to use any web coding (maybe HTML5?), to analyze the tones of a song, specifically a piano song, and give out some kind of code every time a specific tone, or a note is hit, which can then be further used for other stuff?

If not, do you know of any other methods of getting something like this done? I want a webpage to be able to analyze a song by the different notes, and then have something happen when the different notes are getting played.

Comment: I think you would need flash for something like this, but if it's simple enough javascript might do the job.

Html is a markup language, meaning that it can't so anything really "dynamic" by itself, it's just the data, you should never style or be functional with html, all that should go in javascript, or CSS or whatever you use.

Comment: Some questions: 1. is your intention that a user uploads a song, or is it chosen from somewhere, or pre-stored? 2. how soon after uploading or selecting the song do you need the analysis data to be available? These are important questions because they will determine whether you implement the analysis in the browser or on the server.

Comment: It should be something like a user uploading a song, and then as soon as the data is available, it will be able to use it. That's how I have in mind it should be anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I myself only picked up coding recently but now know html and php. I just thought I'd say that doing what you want is definitely not possible for someone that is new to everything. HTML is a markup language, it just organises everything on the page.

To achieve what you want you would need a lot of coding knowledge. Tone recognition is the kind of thing you see on extremely expensive production software such as cubase. I wish it were simple to do such a task as it would come in very handy for the site I have built. However it is not. If you are really set on this idea google something like tone recognition software although I doubt there will be anything suitable that can be easily implemented into a website.

My advice would be either spend a lot of time learning and mastering many front and backed coding platforms or spend a lot of money hiring someone to do it for you.

If you want to accomplish the same task but in a simpler but still intricate way I would scrap the notion of tone recognition. If you had an onscreen keyboard where each key was a form submit button you could then attach some PHP code to each key with an if(isset([''])) function. When a certain key is pressed something is outputted by the code or in PHP words echoed. This would require extensive knowledge of HTML, CSS, PHP and jquery. Probably some others thrown in their too.

You probably won't be able to execute that yourself but it is a much easier and viable approach if you want to get someone to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to coding world I would like to recommend you to do these free online courses from [Udacity](http://www.udacity.com/) which is an awesome initiative from one of the top teachers of coding world to democratize education.

> Udacity is a digital university on a mission to democratize education

Course material is excellent and you can follow subjects on your own pace and many other benefits for free and they will provide you with signed certificated too when you clear final exam of a subject.

I am not connected to Udacity in any way. :) I am myself following some courses even after I have a CS degree.

Now on to your answer your questions :

HTML is a markup language which displays structured data to webpage. It takes data input via forms and pass it on to the backend system and displays the data it receives from the backend system.

There are two major divisions of any website or webapplication :

```
1. Frontend
2. Backend
```

Frontend is what you see on the webpage and how you interact with the webpage.
Backend is actually responsible for providing data for frontend to display. Both of them are nothing without each other.

So what you are trying to achieve can be done on backend only but the input will be taken through HTML. Only HTML is not enough to do this. You need a powerful programming language to do this stuff on the backend.

I would like to tell you this project is very advanced and it takes years of programming experience (and CS degree too but its not mandatory if you are determined enough) to create such project. If its a business idea you better higher someone or some company in software and web development field to build this for you.

If you have any question then simple comment and ask me.

Welcome to the world of softwares and SO too. :)